# How to block internet access to certain programs on Linux

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

Recently, I have encountered a problem of limiting Internet Access to specific programs. Could anybody recommend a good way of doing that, without using any particular software?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The solution for me happened to be straight forward.

1. Create, validate *new group*; add required users to this group:

   - Create: `groupadd no-internet`
   - Validate: `grep no-internet /etc/group`
   - Add user: `useradd -g no-internet username`
     *Note: If you're modifying already existing user you should run: `usermod -a -G no-internet userName`
     check with : `sudo groups userName`*
2. Create a *script* in your path and make it executable:

- Create: `nano /home/username/.local/bin/no-internet`
- Executable: `chmod 755 /home/username/.local/bin/no-internet`
- Content:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sg no-internet "$@"
```

3. Add *iptables rule* for dropping network activity for group *no-internet*:

   - `iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -j DROP`
     *Note: Don't forget to make the changes permanent, so it would be [applied automatically after reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38019/execute-a-script-as-root-at-boot-on-fedora-15-16). Doing it, depends on your Linux distribution.*
4. Check it, for example on Firefox by running: `no-internet "firefox"`

In case you would want to make an exception and allow a program to access *local network*:

- `iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT`
- `iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT`
- `iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -j DROP`

*NOTE:* In case of spawning the rules will be maintained. For example, if you run a program with *no-internet* rule and that program will open browser window, still the rules will be applied.

Comment: A few notes Ilia: Ad 1: - to modify existing user: usermod -a -G groupName userName
- check with : sudo groups userName Ad 3:
- I already have a lot of rules in iptables, The position of the new rule is crucial. should be the first rule in chain OUTPUT. Therefore I use insert : iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -j DROP To allow access to LAN: make sure the ACCEPT rules are above the DENY rule. Works like a charm. Use it for example on Wifiguard. Prog checks wlan for unknown devices, but "phones home" on every start.

Comment: The script will only pass the command. If you try launching a programm with parameters, you should use "$@" instead  of "$1". For some reason, I had to temporarily store it in a variable for bash to process it correctly: cmd="$@"; sg no-internet "${cmd}"

Comment: use "nointernet" instead of "no-internet". For whatever reason Ubuntu 14.04 can't handle the dash when you try to use sg or chgrp (it prompts for a password, then fails).

Comment: unshare -n YourAppToBlock > use "nointernet" instead of "no-internet". perhaps, 'no\\-internet'?

Comment: I tried it like described but for me, after adding me to "no-internet" and set the ip-tables I cannot connect to the internet anymore (with and without the bash script no-internet).

Comment: I would change the second line of the script to be `exec sg no-internet "$@"`.

Comment: @kasperd yeah, thanks. Having _expansion_ is a good idea.

Comment: It would be useful to note that for this manual to work one has to have `xt_owner` module loaded (or built-in), so that `/proc/net/ip_tables_matches` contains a line `owner`. Otherwise you'll get "no chain/target/match by that name" error from `iptables` command. Also, after adding a group one has to `gpasswd` it to some valid password, otherwise `sg` will give you a cryptic `Invalid argument` error after you enter "some" password.

Comment: Not to revive an old thread, but to avoid the password issues, just use `sudo -g no-internet`. Also it's a little simpler to throw this into a shell alias. Also, I wouldn't recommend using `unshare`, since it probably requires root, and you will be running the untrusted program as root.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work when I wanted to use it as a user added to the no-internet group. If you find it more convenient to create a user account with limited network access (e.g. this way you can more easily share file access), use `iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $USERNAME -j DROP`

Comment: Why do we need `item 2`?

Comment: any hint on adjusting these to also allow ipv6?

Answer (score 23):

A more straightforward possibility: use **[firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/basic-usage/)**. It runs the application inside sandbox. At the sandbox, you can control the access of the application to any network or folder in your computer.

To execute a certain application without network access do following:

```
firejail --net=none <application>
```

In that case, "The sandbox looks like a computer without any network interfaces." ([See Network Section in documentation](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/basic-usage/#networking))

For example, `firejail --net=none firefox` will start firefox without any network connection.

**Installation**

See the [Installation documentation](https://firejail.wordpress.com/download-2/).
You should install from the package system in your distribution, or better get [the latest version LTS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/firejail/files/LTS/). (For example, this latest LTS version, `9.56.2`, works also in Ubuntu 16.04.)

Comment: I am getting following warning message: `Warning: an existing sandbox was detected. ping will run without any additional sandboxing features`

Answer (score 11):

From answer for [How to disable Internet connection for a single process](https://askubuntu.com/a/1147420/660555) and [Block network access of a process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83348/198423)

> Then, starting a process without network access is as simple as:
>
> `unshare -n program ...`
>
> This creates an empty network namespace for the process. That is, it
> is run with no network interfaces, including no loopback. In below
> example we add -r to run the program only after the current effective
> user and group IDs have been mapped to the superuser ones (avoid
> sudo):
>
> `unshare -r -n ping google.com`

Comment: I could not run libreoffice6.0 with `firejail`, but your method worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

nftables can set firewall rules based on cgroups (it can be bound to each program), the syntax:

```
socket cgroupv2 level NUM PATH
```

**PATH:**

'PATH' is the one in `/sys/fs/cgroup`, note that the 'PATH' is relative, so you should exclude `/sys/fs/cgroup/` from the absolute path. For example, `/sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/nginx.service` is the cgroup for nginx and its 'PATH' should be `system.slice/nginx.service`.

Most systemd services are confined in cgroups. Use `systemd-cgls` to view the cgroup tree and use `systemd-cgls -u XXX.service` to get the cgroup for a specific service. For example, `systemd-cgls -u nginx.service` returns `/system.slice/nginx.service`.

Note that you should **remove** the first / , so the 'PATH' should be `system.slice/nginx.service`. If your path contains the symbol '@' please use `nft --interactive` to set up your firewall rules, other wise, the symbol would be misinterpreted.

Although cgroups will be setup for every systemd unit automatically, you can modify or create systemd unit files to fine tune the cgroup settings if you have special needs. Theoretically, you can set up rules for all programs in a systemd enabled operating system. See systemd.unit(5) and systemd.slice(5) for more information.

Even the most basic systemd unit is attached to a cgroup:

```
[Unit]
Description="My Program"

[Service]
ExecStart="/usr/bin/my_program"
```

If your do not use systemd, you can also add program to cgroups manually. See cgroups kernel documentation for more info.

**NUM:**

'NUM' indicates the level of cgroups that will be matched in the firewall rule.
In our previous example, `socket cgroupv2 level 2 "system.slice/nginx.service"` matches exactly the nginx service. While `socket cgroupv2 level 1 "system.slice/nginx.service"` matches all the cgroups under "system.slice/", thus not only nginx but other programs in that directory will also be matched, such as "snapd.service".

**A very basic example:**

To prevent nginx from accessing the Internet (assume you already have a inet table named 'filter' and a chain named 'output'):

```
nft add rule inet filter output socket cgroupv2 level 2 "system.slice/nginx.service" drop
```

Comment: If you have a systemd service, you can tell systemd itself to run it in an empty network namespace with `PrivateNetwork=true`; no need for extra tools at that point.